# Closure of the span of an orthonormal basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\left\{e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be an an orthonormal basis for the Hilbert space $\mathcal H$.

Prove that, if $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle\right|^2=\|f\|^2$, $\forall f \in \mathcal{H}$ then $\overline{\operatorname{span}}\left\{e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}=\mathcal{H}$.

I don't know how to start with this problem. I know that if $\left\{e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is an orthonormal basis then $f=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle e_k, \forall f \in \mathcal{H}$ and so $\langle f, g\rangle=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle\left\langle e_k, g\right\rangle, \forall f, g \in \mathcal{H}$. From this we have that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\left|\left\langle f, e_k\right\rangle\right|^2=\|f\|^2, \forall f \in \mathcal{H}$. But how can I infer that $\overline{\operatorname{span}}\left\{e_k\right\}_{k=1}^{\infty}=\mathcal{H}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an orthogonal decomposition
$$ f=\left(f-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle f,e_{k}\rangle e_k\right)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle f,e_{k}\rangle e_{k}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
 \|f\|^2=\left\|f-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k \right\|^2+\sum_{k=1}^{n}|\langle f,e_{k}\rangle|^2.
$$
I'll let you take it from there.

Comment: Thank you! But how could I obtain the claim?

Comment: @Lely : It immediately follows that $\|f\|^2=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle f,e_n\rangle|^2$ for some $f$ iff $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\langle f,e_k\rangle e_k =f$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: Yep, thank you!

Comment: @Lely : You are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $f\in\mathcal{H}$, is there a sequence of (finite) linear combinations of $\{e_k\}_k$ converging to $f$?

Answer (score 1):

We need the following results which I assume to be known:

- $\mathcal{H}^{\perp}=\{0\}$
- $S^{\perp\perp}=\overline{S}$

Let $S:=span\{e_{k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ thus we want to prove $\overline{S}=\mathcal{H}$.
This is equivalent to proving $S^{\perp}=\{0\}$, since $\overline{S}=S^{\perp\perp}=(S^{\perp})^{\perp}=\{0\}^{\perp}=\mathcal{H}^{\perp\perp}=\overline{\mathcal{H}}=\mathcal{H}$.

We now show $S^{\perp}=\{0\}$.
Let $f \in S^{\perp}$ then $f \perp e_{k}$ or equivalently $\langle f, e_{k}\rangle=0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.
Using our assumption we can conclude $$||f||^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|\langle f, e_{k} \rangle|^{2}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}0=0.$$ Thus $f=0$ and hence $S^{\perp}=\{0\}$.